# Setting up database access

Tags: database, security

Which is the better way to set up access on some databases that my web apps query.  I can only think of one pro for one and one con for the other, so I need some other input before making a final decision.

Option 1 – 10 apps, 10 databases, 1 Service Accounts for each app (User does not have direct access) 
All query requests go through the Service Account to the database.  The con I can think of is that there is no record of who sent the request, just that the SA accessed the db with a request.

Option 2 – 10 apps, 10 databases, User has direct access (no Service Account)

All query requests from the app go directly to the db and each request is logged, identifying who sent the request from what app.  This setup could be locked down further by allowing the specific app access only to db/tables/columns that it needs to complete the request/query.  The obvious pro is there would be no anonymous requests; all requests could be traced back to the requester and not just to a SA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by Service Account you refer to a functional account or database account for the application. This is the way to go. If you need to log who did the request your application should have user authentication and do the logging of the request.

The other alternative of a database account per user is not scalable and if you have to provide a database id for each user, which the user will be using to connect, it also has security implications.

By having the application between the user and the database you isolate the database from the outside and the only access is what the applications permits.